# PATH and CLASSPATH variables in java

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, path, classpath

I have just started with jsp. I have downloaded tomcat server. Now when I tried to connect a db with using jdbc. I failed to connect it with MySQL and PostgreSQL. The reasons are:

My java's path is set in PATH variable as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin

Now for setting path for db (MySQL or PostgreSQL), I am using CLASSPATH variable as E:\XX\XX-XX.jar;

The problem is that when I set classpath my JAVA(not jsp) programs stopped working with an error: Unable to load the class.

and I am also not able to connect yet with any db. Can someone please guide me?

P.S. I am using windows 8.1 and I am not using any IDE.

Comment: Could you try adding current directory indicator which is `.`. Make classpath like E:\XX\XX-XX.jar;.

Comment: Are you overriding the java path or just appending your db path with already set java path?

Comment: Don't, ever, set the CLASSPATH. The classpath of a web application consists in the set of jar files inside the WEB-INF/lib directory of the deployed war file (and in the WEB-INF/classes directory). If you want help, don't just say "I'm unable to". Post the relevant code, and the exact and complete error message.

Comment: @Ozgen Wow. Thanks. It worked! Now I can run java programs too.
Now please help me in connecting db with jsp!

Comment: Can you elaborate what the problem is now for connecting to DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try adding current directory indicator which is .. Make classpath like E:\XX\XX-XX.jar;.

Comment: Wow. Thanks. It worked! Now I can run java programs too. Now please help me in connecting db with jsp!

Comment: This is different from this question that I have asked above. Can I have your email id or Facebook username?

Comment: I think it is better you post the question here, people will also be able to follow it here. I will be waiting your post.